# unresolved type Point when using paper.Point

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, paperjs

import {paper} from 'paper/dist/paper-full.min'

is the import statement I'm using. I am getting unresolved type error on using Point inside paper

Comment: I think you want `import {Point} from 'paper';`. Then just use it like so: `new Point(10, 10)`.

Comment: I still see cannot resolve point warning

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle or something like that ?